# pandas datareader raises AttributeError: module 'pandas.io' has no attribute 'data'

Tags: python, pandas

This is a code I am trying

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt    
import pandas as pd
ticker = 'GLD'
begdate = '2014-11-11'
enddate = '2016-11-11'
data1 = pd.io.data.DataReader(ticker,'yahoo',dt.datetime(2014,11,11),dt.datetime(2016,11,11))
gld_df = pd.DataFrame(data1)
date_df = pd.to_datetime(list(gld_df.index))
adj_close_df = list(gld_df["Adj Close"])
plt.plot(date_df,adj_close_df)
plt.title("SPDR Gold Shares ")
```

Its giving me the below error. Few days back, there was no error when I had tried the same code.

```
runfile('D:/Quant/MSQF/4 - Algorithms 1/3-Sorting/Mini Project 2_v2.py', wdir='D:/Quant/MSQF/4 - Algorithms 1/3-Sorting')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-10-db75eb5622f8>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('D:/Quant/MSQF/4 - Algorithms 1/3-Sorting/Mini Project 2_v2.py', wdir='D:/Quant/MSQF/4 - Algorithms 1/3-Sorting')

  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 714, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 89, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "D:/Quant/MSQF/4 - Algorithms 1/3-Sorting/Mini Project 2_v2.py", line 18, in <module>
    data1 = pd.io.data.DataReader(ticker,'yahoo',dt.datetime(2014,11,11),dt.datetime(2016,11,11))

AttributeError: module 'pandas.io' has no attribute 'data'
```

I am using Anaconda, Python 3.x . Is this a problem with Pandas or some issue with my system?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

pandas has removed that functionality and it is now offered as a different package ([link](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/remote_data.html)):

> DataReader The sub-package pandas.io.data is removed in favor of a
>   separately installable pandas-datareader package. This will allow the
>   data modules to be independently updated to your pandas installation.
>   The API for pandas-datareader v0.1.1 is the same as in pandas v0.16.1.
>   (GH8961)
>
> You should replace the imports of the following:
>
> ```
> from pandas.io import data, wb
> ```
>
> With the following:
>
> ```
> from pandas_datareader import data, wb
> ```

Install [`pandas_datareader`](https://pandas-datareader.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) with `pip install pandas-datareader`
 and replace the code with the following:

```
from pandas_datareader import data
import datetime as dt
ticker = 'GLD'
begdate = '2014-11-11'
enddate = '2016-11-11'
data1 = data.DataReader(ticker,'yahoo',dt.datetime(2014,11,11),dt.datetime(2016,11,11))
```

Comment: FYI - ```pip install data_reader``` didn't work for me. It was ```pip install pandas_datareader```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you just need 2 things
First uninstall the lib -

```
pip uninstall pandas-datareader
```

And then need to install it using **pip3** (Please notice it is pip3)

```
pip3 install pandas-datareader
```

And then use -

```
from pandas_datareader import data, wb
#..............

#................
data.DataReader()
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you updated pandas to a newer version which no longer supports io.data

See here for fix
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/remote_data.html

Answer (score 0):

If you import it directly, you get a more verbose import error:

```
from pandas.io.data import DataReader
```

> ImportError: The pandas.io.data module is moved to a separate package
>   (pandas-datareader). After installing the pandas-datareader package
>   (https://github.com/pydata/pandas-datareader), you can change the
>   import `from pandas.io import data, wb` to `from pandas_datareader
>   import data, wb`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do

```
import pandas.io.data as web
```

then you can easily execute

```
web.DataReader(stuff)
```

Also, don't forget to `import datetime as dt` otherwise you'll catch another exception. Also, I've just was late for 1 sec :(

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, here is the solution:

```
pip install pandas_datareader
```

Change `import pandas.io.data` to `from pandas_datareader import data, wb`

Use `data.DataReader()` to get data from Internet

updated*

good luck~~

Comment: `$ pip install pandas-datareader`
See https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pandas-datareader

Comment: First, you need to do: