# Pandas.io.datareader not working in Google Colab

Tags: python, pandas, google-colaboratory, pandas-datareader

So I am following a book Python for Finance.
A simple code is laid out in the first chapter, but it doesnt work.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pandas.io.data as web
goog = web.DataReader('GOOG', data_source='google',
 start='3/14/2009', end='4/14/2014')
goog.tail()
```

Output

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-44-cffd761e0041> in <module>
      1 import numpy as np
      2 import pandas as pd
----> 3 import pandas.io.data as web
      4 goog = web.DataReader('GOOG', data_source='google',
      5  start='3/14/2009', end='4/14/2014')

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas.io.data'
```

How do I work around this? Checked web, couldnt find relevant info.

Thanks

The expected output was ..

```
Out[2]: Open High Low Close Volume
 Date
 2014-04-08 542.60 555.00 541.61 554.90 3152406
 2014-04-09 559.62 565.37 552.95 564.14 3324742
 2014-04-10 565.00 565.00 539.90 540.95 4027743
 2014-04-11 532.55 540.00 526.53 530.60 3916171
 2014-04-14 538.25 544.10 529.56 532.52 2568020
 5 rows × 5 columns
```

This is from the text book.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pandas datareader raises AttributeError: module 'pandas.io' has no attribute 'data'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40816169/pandas-datareader-raises-attributeerror-module-pandas-io-has-no-attribute-da)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the pandas-datareader Python package. Some data sources that were previously available may no longer be available; a list of supported data sources is provided below.

**Command to install required package (in Colab);**

```
!pip install pandas-datareader
```

**Code;**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas_datareader import data as web
goog = web.DataReader('GOOG', data_source='stooq',
 start='3/14/2009', end='4/14/2014')
goog.tail()
```

**Supported Sources;**

yahoo, iex, iex-tops, iex-last, iex-last, bankofcanada, stooq, iex-book, enigma, fred, famafrench, oecd, eurostat, nasdaq, quandl, moex, tiingo, yahoo-actions, yahoo-dividends, av-forex, av-forex-daily, av-daily, av-daily-adjusted, av-weekly, av-weekly-adjusted, av-monthly, av-monthly-adjusted, av-intraday, econdb, naver